# JSON / PowerShell - store ps variables in JSON and execute when converted to powershell object

Tags: json, powershell

Quick and dirty: I need a way to store a variable inside a JSON File. Let's show an example:

**JSON File**

```
{
   "Computername": "$env:COMPUTERNAME"
}
```

**PowerShell**

`Get-Content -Path Filename.json | ConvertFrom-Json`

Expecting output:

```
Computername
--------------
XYZ1234
```

Real Output (Problem):

```
Computername
--------------
$env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Do I need to go with escaping? I couldnt figure it out how to solve this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a string as the value, you can use ExpandString to evaluate it.

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString((Get-Content -Path Filename.json)) | ConvertFrom-Json
```